# Safety in Liposomal Amphotericin B

Tags: cell-biology, medicine, mycology

From reading about Amphotericin B antifungal, I understand it is quite a toxic medicine for kidney, but I am not able to find any details as to how Liposomal version of same medication is so safe, in end are not we eating same chemical, how doe s liposomal version become less toxic?

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question.  Initially, [the mechanism for the reduced toxicity (1992) was unknown](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/21761074_Liposomal_and_Lipid_Formulations_of_Amphotericin_B), as stated in the abstract of a well-cited paper.  [A paper from Oxford Radcliffe hospital in 1998](https://www.clinicalmicrobiologyandinfection.com/article/S1198-743X(14)64358-5/fulltext) said that 15.5% of all their spending on antimicrobial agents was on these new, expensive drugs, available in many formulations, and argued the evidence supporting their use was scanty with a key study available only as an abstract.  [A review in 2013](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23729001/) seems more favorable, but I haven't looked at the full text - by that time, one of the products with reactions at the injection site had been withdrawn, and the costs were coming down.  [At the level of the individual](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24787480/), these stories are poignant.

The paper from Oxford Radcliffe wrote of one formulation *"It has been suggested that the large particle size of ABLC (1.6–11 μm) leads to its rapid clearance by reticuloendothelial cells, resulting in lower plasma levels."*  This idea has been pursued in numerous other papers ([example](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0928098709000736)), but I lack the expertise to evaluate it against other potential explanations.